# Easier way to determine a certain property of some primes?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm curious about one property of some primes, and if there is some sort of test that can confirm or deny that a prime has said property without doing all of the calculations.

For any integer $n$, there are $n-1$ possibilities for the value of $mod(m, n)$, where $m$ is also an integer. What I'm curious about is whether or not for some prime $p$, if you define a series $S$ such that $S$ contains:

$mod(10^0, p)$, $mod(10^1, p)$, $mod(10^2, p)$... $mod(10^{p-2}, p)$

Will $S$ contain all of the integers $1<= n <= p-1$?

For example, the remainders for the number 7 are as follows:

$mod(10^0, 7) = 1$

$mod(10^1, 7) = 3$

$mod(10^2, 7) = 2$

$mod(10^3, 7) = 6$

$mod(10^4, 7) = 4$

$mod(10^5, 7) = 5$

Which, as you can see, covers all of the integers $1 <= n <= 6$

I've written a program in Java that checks the first $n$ integers and sees:

A) if they are prime, and if they are:

B) whether or not they satisfy the property

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class mainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 1000;
        ArrayList<Integer> doesSatisfy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> doesNotSatisfy = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> primes  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int p = 2; p < n; p++) {
            if (isPrime(p, primes)) {
                if (allNumbersCovered(p)) {
                    doesSatisfy.add(p);
                } else {
                    doesNotSatisfy.add(p);
                }
            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < doesSatisfy.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print((i !=0? ", ": "The primes that satisfy the property are:\n(") + doesSatisfy.get(i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < doesNotSatisfy.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print((i !=0? ", ": ")\nThe primes that do not satisfy the property are:\n(") + doesNotSatisfy.get(i));
        }
        System.out.print(")\nThat's all folks!");
    }
    public static boolean allNumbersCovered(int p) {
        ArrayList<Integer> covered = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < p-1; i++) {
            covered.add(0);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < p - 1; i++) {
            if (mod(i,  p) > 0) {
                covered.set(mod(i, p)-1, 1);
            }
        }
        boolean allThere = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < p-1; i++) {
            if (covered.get(i) == 0) {
                allThere = false;
            }
        }
        return allThere;
    }
    public static int mod(int n, int p) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 1;
        }else {
            return (mod(n-1, p)*10)%p;
        }
    }
    public static boolean isPrime(int p, ArrayList<Integer> primes) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {
            if (p%primes.get(i) == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            primes.add(p);
        }
        return isPrime;
    }
}
```

Two things to note:

1) I've never had any formal schooling in CS, and I'm 15, so my mathematical notation and/or programming may not be perfect.

2) I've tested the first 10,000 numbers and this property doesn't hold true for any non-primes, which intuitively makes sense, but I have no actual proof for it, so any help in that regard would be cool too.

Comment: All the residues occur if and only if the so-called order of $10$ modulo $p$ is equal to $p-1$. This is the smallest positive integer $k$ with the property $$10^k\equiv 1\mod p$$ If we have $k=p-1$, we can conclude that $p$ is prime (that means the property actually only holds for primes). But the converse is not true. A prime need not have this property.

Comment: Determining this order can be extremely difficult because we need the prime factorization of $p-1$, which might be infeasible in practice, if $p$ is very large.

Comment: I’m not super familiar with modulus jargon, and I’ve done my best to look stuff up, so my best understanding is that you mean that only primes have the property that the pattern of remainders repeats after p-1 powers of 10 (correct me if I’m wrong). Do you mind explaining why we can conclude p is prime? I understand why it cannot be true for any even numbers besides 2 and for multiples of 5, but my intuition breaks down for other numbers. Edit: after seeing your second comment it seems like this is a solid bit over my head and I’ve got some learning to do - apologies for my lack of knowledge

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not completely trivial to prove this. We can derive this result from Euler's theorem which however uses the totient function. It states : If $a$ and $p$ are coprime numbers , then $$a^{\varphi(p)}\equiv 1\mod p$$ holds. This is true for every integer $p>1$, not just the primes. $\varphi(n)$ is the number of integers in the range $[1,n]$, which are coprime to $n$.

Comment: The order must be a divisor of $\varphi(p)$ and $\varphi(p)$ is bounded by $p-1$. So, if the order is $p-1$, then we also have $\varphi(p)=p-1$ and this is only possible is $p$ is prime. I know, not easy. You have to study some number theoretical topics.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense - I've never heard of the totient function before but the way you explained it made it easy enough for me to understand. I appreciate the help & explanation!

Comment: See [primitive root modulo n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n). This is a basic topic in elementary number theory.

Comment: I'll look into it - thanks @BillDubuque